# Qt was built without ICU support, WebKit was disabled. VS2012

Tags: qt5, icu

I want to compile QT 5.0.1 in Windows 7 x64, but when I configure qt, that I get:

Qt is now configured for building. Just run nmake.
To reconfigure, run nmake confclean and configure.

- d:/Libraries/Qt/5.0.1/qtbase/bin/qmake d:/Libraries/Qt/5.0.1/qtsdk.pro
  Project MESSAGE: WebKit: Qt was built without ICU support, WebKit disabled.

I compiled ICU 50 in my machine and there are tests for icu, x32 Release and Debug mode failed them, but x64 are fine. I wrote to system variables ICU/bin and ICU/bin64.

So, please tell how to compile Qt with ICU and WebKit.

Answer (score 4):

The below is an example build configuration:

```
configure \
    -prefix C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1 -platform win32-msvc2012 -opensource -c++11 \
    -make tools -make libs -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl \
    -icu \
    -I D:\Projects\icu4c-51_1\icu\include \
    -L D:\Projects\icu4c-51_1\icu\lib64
```

To include Webkit, you must enable `-icu` and add its include and library path to the command options.

The ICU build type must be the same as Qt, that is, x86 or x64.